# How to access Docker build context path inside Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have Dockerfile defined in a directory

```
C:\work\Personal\API\api-service
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-8 AS BUILD_IMAGE 
COPY api-service /usr/src/app/api-service
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/app  
RUN mvn -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml clean install
```

I am trying to run `docker build C:\work\Personal\API\api-service` from `C:`

This results in error saying

```
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder483308674/api-init-service: no such file or directory
```

In order from me to copy the source code from local machine to docker, i need to know the location of build context folder inside my `Dockerfile`.

Is there any way to access build context folder passed to `docker build` command inside a `Dockerfile`?

In my local machine i can run `docker build` command from same directory as `Dockerfile` is located. But from CI tool i will not know where the `docker build`command will be executed. Hence if i know the `docker build` context path passed as argument, i can copy the source code into docker image based on the context path.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need docker build context location known inside your `dockerfile`.

What you need to know is:

- Location of you build context. (say `C:\work\Personal\mycontext` which contains files and folders that you need to copy inside docker container)
- Location of `dockerfile` (say `C:\work\Personal\API\api-service\Dockerfile`)
- Also you need to know relative file path structure of your context. Like

```
- C:\work\Personal\mycontext
  |
   - scripts
     |
     - start.sh
  |
  - create.py
  |
  - target
    |
    - maven
      |
      - abc.jar
```

In this case your `dockerfile` will contain appropriate commands like `COPY scripts /scripts` that copy these files assuming its running from the context folder `C:\work\Personal\mycontext`

Your docker build command will be

```
docker build -f C:\work\Personal\API\api-service\Dockerfile -t image:version1 C:\work\Personal\mycontext
```

**Note:** Here `-f` option specify location of dockerfile in this case its `C:\work\Personal\API\api-service\Dockerfile` and `C:\work\Personal\mycontext` specify location of docker build context.

Irrespective of location from where the docker build commands runs, it will work as long as you provide exact location of `dockerfile` and docker build `context`.

More info [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#specify-a-dockerfile--f).

Comment: what If I need to add a check for different build context in my dockerfile? Then I do need the build context i.e. different projects in the same directory share the same Dockefile.

Comment: Maybe put a config file in each of the various projects, the contents of which drive config-dependent logic in the Dockerfile.